How can I configure a desk reject period for area chairs in OpenReview?
I use OpenReview for a conference. After the paper submission deadline and before the review period starts, I'd like to give one week for area chairs to skim through the paper submissions to do desk rejects. How can I configure a desk reject period for area chairs in OpenReview?
